# Plotting in matlab given a negative to positive domain

Tags: matlab, plot

I am working on code for a homework assignment which we are to plot a specific equation in Matlab given a domain here is how the question reads.

Plot the function f1(x) = A x3 + B x2 + C x + D on the domain −10 ≤ x ≤ 10, with
A= 0.3, B = 1.5, C = -2.0 and D = - 4.0. Use dx = 0.1. Use the plot command:
plot(x,f1)

My problem is starting with the -10 value as the first variable in the plot. It comes out with an error message "attempted to access (-1); index must be a positive integer or logical. This is how my code reads.

```
clc
clear all
close all

dx = 0.1;
xlow = -10;

for i = 1 : 21

x(i) = (xlow + (i-1)) * dx;
f1(x(i)) = 0.3 * x(i)^3 + 1.5 x(i)^2 -2.0 x(i) -4.0

end
figure(1)
plot(x,f1)
title('Homework plot 1')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
```

I know most of my code works its just getting the negative domain to work can anyone offer any help?

Comment: `f1` is not defined anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 4):

I see several problems with your script.

1. Within your loop you should be getting an out of bounds exception, as you are referencing a negative bound in the f1 matrix. When your loop first runs it will try to access the "-10th" element in f1, `f1(-10)`, and should break.
2. Your loop does not meet your professors guidelines. The professor requires your `delta=.1` in the `x` domain of `-10:10`. This means there should be a total of 200 steps within your loop, and 200 elements in each matrix (x ant f1).

Unless your professor specifically instructed you to use a loop to populate your matrices, this assignment can be done without any loops.

```
x=[-10:.1:10];
f1=(x.^3*.3)+(x.^2*1.5)+(x*-2)-4
figure(1)
plot(x,f1)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
```

This script above generates the `x` matrix with a delta of .1, `dx=.1`. Next I generate the `f1` matrix using [basic matrix manipulation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/matrix-manipulation.html), so no loop is required.

Alternatively, if a loop is required by your professor you must first calculate the amount of steps required for your loop by dividing the magnitude of your `x domain` by your delta.

```
magnitude = xhigh-xlow;
steps = magnitude/dx;
for i = 1:steps+1
    x(i) = xlow + (i*dx-dx);
    f1(i) = 0.3 * x(i)^3 + 1.5 x(i)^2 -2.0 x(i) -4.0
end
```

`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `f1(x(i))` inside the loop. If `x(i)` is -10, that means you are trying to save `f1(-10)`.

`f1(-10)` makes sense in mathematical notation, but it doesn't in any programming language, as what it is inside the parenthesis is the index in memory!

You can solve that error by just `f(i)` , so for any given **positive integer** `i`, you will have `f(i)` that corresponds to the x value `x(i)`.